# How can I control the flashlight on the phone?

Tags: android

When I do some research on the Android SDK website, I know that I have to grant the permission "FLASHLIGHT" in order to use the light. However, I cannot find in the API any methods to control the flash light. But I believe there is a way because I can see so many apps doing this in the Android Market. How can I do so?

Comment: Long time ago, but did you manage to find a way to control the flashlight? Do you mind sharing it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Without any error checking, but something like this:

```
Camera mycam = Camera.open();
Parameters p = mycam.getParameters();
p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
mycam.setParameters(p);
//time passes
p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
mycam.release();
```